# Qt creator 4.4 Win7 (on Qt 5.9.1); Debug global string variables not printed (<no such value>)

Tags: c++, qt, gdb, qt-creator, pretty-print

I am giving a try to the new Qt EDI on Win, and in debug mode I am unable to "pretty print" string **global** variables in the "Locals and Expressions" viewer. What is amazing, is that the **local** string variables are printed correctly. Is there something to do with that problem. I tried a couple of times to reinstall but unfortunately the problem is still there. To illustrate, I tried this:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

string line, statement;

void func(void)    //Just to illustrate local vars.
{
    string s1, s2;
    s1="s1";
    s2="s2";
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{ 
    func();
    line="This is line";
    statement="this is statement";
    cout << line << " and " << statement << endl;
    getchar();    
    return 0;
}
```

s1 and s2 are correctly printed in the debugger viewer, but line and statement are indicated like: no such value.

Comment: Try `qDebug()  << line << " and " << statement;` so you can see it in debug output. Using `std::cout` implies different stream buffering so you may miss the output.

Comment: @AlexanderVX:   Yes, but in fact I want to see them in the "Local and Expressions" viewers of the debug interface. The string local variables (s1 and s2) are correctly shown, but why the global string variables are not (line and statement), which indicate <no such value> ? Also, to be more generic, I modified the source, to a standard C++ (no Qt), and it is the same pb. Seems to be related to an install/setting problem, or GDB or...

Comment: Huh, I was confused by "printed" and std::cout while you only talk about debug view "Locals and Expressions". It just Qt Creator being not perfect then. On Windows MS Visual Studio 2015 and later has some nice Qt extension in the Store (?) (no need for Qt AddIn) anymore but I have not look for quite a few time already. And MS VS is much better debug tool there.